# ostream implementatuon using printf

Tags: c++, printf, ostream

How to implement `ostream`-like class from scratch using `printf` only?
For me looks like the problem is in choosing the format string ,which is actually equal to the identifying input`s type and treating precision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean something that overloads `operator<<` by "an `ostream`-like class". It's easy to identify the type of the argument to a function just by having overloads. For example, you might have:

```
ostreamlike& ostreamlike::operator<<(int x)
{
  printf("%d", x);
  return *this;
}

ostreamlike& ostreamlike::operator<<(float x)
{
  printf("%f", x);
  return *this;
}
```

The format of the output is determined by whichever overload is picked.

Answer (score 1):

Think, it could be something like that

```
#include <stdio.h>

class ostreamlike {
public:
  ostreamlike(FILE* f_): f(f_) {}

  ostreamlike& write(int n) {
    fprintf(f, "%d", n);
    return *this;
  }

  ostreamlike& write(const char* n) {
    fprintf(f, "%s", n);
    return *this;
  }

private:
  FILE* f;
};

// operator for types that is supported ostreamlike internally
template <typename type>
ostreamlike& operator<<(ostreamlike& stream, const type& data) {
  return stream.write(data);
}

// external implementations to write using ostreamlike
ostreamlike& operator<<(ostreamlike& stream, bool data) {
  return stream.write(data ? "true" : "false");
}

int main() {
  ostreamlike s(stdout);
  s << "hello " << 1 << " : " << true << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how close to the real `ostream` you want to be. Assuming you want to do it properly you would also need a `streambuf` derived class. `ostream` only does the formatting, the actual I/O is done by an internal `streambuf` derived class. Since `streambuf` does unformatted I/O you would need to use `fwrite` not `printf`.

If your goal is just to do I/O on an already existing `FILE*` pointer this is the way to go. You derive one class from `streambuf`, say `streambuf_with_FILE` and then you derive another class from `ostream` say `ostream_with_FILE`. `streambuf_with_FILE` overrides the appropriate methods to do the actual I/O and `ostream_with_FILE` has an internal `streambuf_with_FILE` object. There's actually very little code required.